# Adding a column in Dataframe with a specific property in python

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[2,3],[1]],'b':[2,4,1]})
```

which looks like,

```
    a       b
0   [1, 2]  2
1   [2, 3]  4
2   [1]     1
```

Now, I want to add a column in this dataframe whose elements are that value in each list of column 'a' whose absolute difference with corresponding value in column 'b' is minimum.
i.e. I want to add a column 'c' in my dataframe, such that my df becomes,

```
   a     b  c
0 [1,2]  2  2
1 [2,3]  4  3
2 [1]    1  1
```

I tried using lambda function, but couldn't do it.

Comment: could you show what have you tried?

Comment: I couldn't write the code for it, I tried to do it using lambda but got confused while writing the function.  I thought of changing each series(column 'a' and 'b') to numpy array and tried to make a column whose each element is a list containing the absolute differences of list elements of column 'a' and element of 'b'. But couldn't do that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the column using zip and store the index of min absolute result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[2,3],[1]],'b':[2,4,1]})
c_col = []

for x, y in zip(df['a'], df['b']):
    array = abs(np.array(x)-y)
    c_col.append(x[array.argmin(axis=0)])

df['c'] = c_col
print(df)
```

Output :

```
        a  b  c
0  [1, 2]  2  2
1  [2, 3]  4  3
2     [1]  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[2,3],[1]],'b':[2,4,1]})

df2 = df.explode('a')
df2['diff'] = (df2['a'] - df2['b']).abs()
df2 = df2.sort_values('diff')
df['c'] = df2.groupby(df2.index).head(1)['a']
print(df)
```

It gives:

```
        a  b  c
0  [1, 2]  2  2
1  [2, 3]  4  3
2     [1]  1  1
```